What extended do ruby
What extended does in this code?
class << self
    def extended(klass)
      klass.class_exec do
        define_method :supported_attrs do
          that_klass = self.class
          that_klass.const_defined?(:ATTRS) ? that_klass.const_get(:ATTRS) : []
        end
      end
    end
  end

https://github.com/lokalise/ruby-lokalise-api/blob/2d78458cbb16fa62d9f6018e79b7ea5da53b77f6/lib/ruby_lokalise_api/concerns/attrs_loadable.rb#L8
There is no use it in the project
Only supported_attrs
Where does Klass come from?
There no mention extended in the project

It's a built-in callback, see Module#extended

The Module#extended hook is automatically called by Ruby and the argument klass is the module or class where extend was called.

So if you're not familiar with the extend function, the short version of it is that will add methods from the specified module into a class. When you call extend, the .extended method is called on the module, with the class as its parameter:
module MyModule
  def self.extended(klass)
    p klass
  end
end

class MyClass
  extend MyModule
  # => Will print "MyClass"
end

So in your case, you can look for instances where the module is being extend'ed to find where those methods will be added.
